# Construct $a,b$ such that $f(x) = x \sin(1/x)$ for $x \neq 0$ does not have mean value property for any $c$ in $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_n(x) = x^n \sin(1/x)$ if $x \neq 0$, else $0$.  For all $n \in \mathbb{N} > 1$, this is continuous and differentiable, so that the Mean Value Theorem applies.

Since $f_1$ is *not* differentiable at $0$, the MVT does not apply, and it *may* be possible to find $a < b$ such that there does not exist a $c$ such that $a < c < b$ and $f'(c) = \frac{f(b) - f(a)}{b-a}$.

How can I find or construct such $a, b$? Clearly, they cannot both be positive or both negative.  Can either be zero?

Additionally: Intuitively, is the reason that $f_1$ is not differentiable at zero because, unlike higher $f_n$, the amplitude of $f_1$ decreases too slowly? Can this intuition be made clearer?

Comment: Hi:) we have $f'_1(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\cdot \cos(1/x)\cdot x + \sin(1/x)\cdot 1=-\frac{1}{x}\cdot \cos(1/x) + \sin(1/x)$ for every $x\neq 0$. For every $a,b,y\in \mathbb R$ with $a<0<b$, there is a $x\in (a,0)\cup (0,b)$ with $f'(x)=y$. We can also say $f((a,0)\cup (0,b))=\mathbb R$

Comment: @Jochen Does that mean that $f_1$ "happens" to have the mean value property "by chance," that is, even though the MVT doesn't guarantee it?

Comment: Yes, of course, I think so.

Comment: The conditions of MVT are sufficient but not necessary. This mean that if $f: [a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is such that there exists a point $c\in (a,b)$ where the derivative *exists* and is equal to $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$, this **does not** imply that the hypotheses of MVT are satisfied, as the example in the comment by @Jochen shows.