# Is there a stronger form of the Mean Value Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis

For continuous functions that are not differentiable, such as $x \mapsto to |x|$ or $x \mapsto x \sin(1/x)$, some fail to have the mean value property (like $|x|$) but [some still do](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4562957/construct-a-b-such-that-fx-x-sin1-x-for-x-neq-0-does-not-have-mean?noredirect=1#comment9599799_4562957).

Is there a way to characterize these continuous, nondifferentiable functions that still have the mean value property? That is, there a way to strengthen the Mean Value Theorem so that it applies to *certain* non-differentiable functions (for an adequate definition of *certain*)?

Comment: the locally Lipschitz functions?

Comment: @Masacroso the OP already excluded $x\mapsto |x|$